# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, SUBCODE=0x0)

Tags: objective-c, swift

When I run my app, I get the error in these lines:

```
ballonview = (cell!.contentView.viewWithTag(0)!.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView)!
label = (cell!.contentView.viewWithTag(0)!.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel)
```

Here is the original code in objective-c, but I want it in swift

```
balloonView = (UIImageView *)[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:1];
label = (UILabel *)[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:2];
```

So, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of those are associated with storyboard elements youll need to make sure they are all properly connected and identified. In my experience thats the first place I need to check when there is a crash involving UI elements.

Also, it would be extremely beneficial to unwrap all those optionals in a safe manner as well. Three bangs in the same line is a giant red flag.